# passing data between viewController and UIView

Tags: objective-c, properties

When I pass data between `ViwControllers` I have a great result:

```
    //ClassA
//.h
#import "ClassB.h"
@class ClassB;
@interface...

@property (nonatomic, strong) ClassB *classBObj;

    //.m
    -(void)ViewDidLoad
    {
    self.classBObj = [[ClassB alloc] init];
    }
    -(IBAction)PassingData:(id)sender
    {
    self.classBObj.intValue = 3;
    }
```

This is `ClassB` describe

```
    //ClassB
//.h
#import "ClassA"
@property (retain) NSNumber intValue;
```

That's it ! `intValue` has value equal 3. But if i try to do the same thing between `ViewController` and `UIView` I receive nil in property (of UIView). How to pass data from `ViewController` not only another `ViewController`? Thanks everybody.

Comment: is your app using ARC or non-ARC?

Comment: I check it by this code  `NSString *dummy = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];` and i get an error `ARC forbids explicit message of 'autorelease'`. So I use ARC

Answer (score 0):

Use strong instead of retain.

`@property (strong) NSNumber intValue;`

Also wen you are sending an value to `NSNumber` send an NSNumber so change your line of code like this

```
self.classBObj.intValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];
```

Comment: Thanks, I've done it. But still it's nil. If I do it between ViewControllers there is no problem

Comment: Is your view a subclass of UIView?

Comment: Try printing the value of `self.classBObj.intValue` before and after assigning the value to it..`-(IBAction)PassingData:(id)sender
    { NSLog(@"%@", self.classBObj.intValue);
    self.classBObj.intValue = 3;   NSLog(@"%@", self.classBObj.intValue);
    }`    also consider changing the name of the instance variable to something else since `intValue` is a method in `NSNumber`.

Comment: Also is there particular reason why you use an `NSNumber`, if not just declare the property as `@property (assign) NSInteger anIntegerValue;`